# Get the value of varible a watch when debugging Intellij Idea plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm developing new Intellij Idea plugin. I need to get variable (or watch) value when debugging an application and display its value (variable's) in the plugin window. Even better would be If I can detect whether this value has changed. I know I can use some hashing function and compare. But if Idea gives me the information it would be easier :-).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need more details on this, what variables do you plan to get and how? What language do you debug?

Comment: I'm using Python so the IDE is PyCharm. The type of the variable is some kind of image, lets' call it `CustomImage`.